# web applications deployment in 2019 minrole environment

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, web-application

Please pardon my limited knowledge (n00b).

```
When deploying in an onprem 2019 multi server mirole environment. Do we ;

i) assign the A record against a WFE device and deploy web application via CA from the (named ) WFE device 

.... or ...

ii) assign the A record against the CA host device and and deploy web-app via CA on CA host device ? 

I have been researching this online for almost a week now and cant seem to find an answer to it.
Or if there is documented information on this online, paid or otherwise, please advise.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The A record needs to point at the WFE. If you have multiple WFEs, you need to put a load balancer in front of the WFEs and point the A record at a virtual IP (VIP).